# Threaded function does not behave as I expect it to

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono, xamarin.ios

This is (roughly) what I have:

```
class A
{
    public bool IsInUpdate = false;
    public void Update()
    {
        IsInUpdate = true;

        //(...do stuff...)

        IsInUpdate = false;
    }
}

class B
{
    A a_inst;
    System.Threading.Thread physicsThread = null;

        void Draw()
        {
            physicsThread = new System.Threading.Thread(a_inst.Update);
            physicsThread.Start();
        }


    void Update()
    {
        while(physicsThread.IsAlive)
        {
            // Right here there can be cases where physicsThread.IsAlive is true but IsInUpdate is false, how does that happen?
        }

        (...do stuff...)
    }


}
```

Question is in the comments of the code. Basically the physics thread instance says it's alive but the function it's calling has clearly been finished calling (as can be seen by the bool being set to false).

Any ideas why this happens? All I want to do is make sure the update function in class B does not execute until the threaded update function of class A has executed...

Comment: I tried to edit your post to format the code, but it doesn't currently make sense, because you're trying to declare Draw() *within* the Update() method. Please tidy up your post and formatting.

Comment: sorry I just noticed that and fixed it, draw and update are seperate functions.

Comment: Assuming a_inst gets filled somewhere, right before the thread has started and after it has finished a_inst.IsInUpdate will be false in the while. What is the real problem here?

Comment: The code is still broken, you'd get a NullPointerException in `new System.Threading.Thread(a_inst.Update);`.

Comment: btw, a tight loop on `IsAlive` is a very bad way to wait... ***especially*** against a field (which can get register-cached). Personally, I'd just use a `lock` here - job done

Comment: @Marino Šimić The problem is it appears there's a mismatch between the functions execution and the thread.IsAlive bool. I'm sure this is expecte dbehaviour but I just want to know why that is.

Comment: @skolima I wasn't trying to make a perfectly working set of code, simply putting up a skeleton example of my real world problem

Comment: @Marc Gravell how would I use a lock?

Comment: @meds I'll update my answer to show

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `IsInUpdate` is simply a public field (and non-`volatile` at that), there are ***no*** guarantees about what you see; the normal sensible rules about what you see only apply on a single thread, and you have not guarded any of this data. There is also an edge-case around the *start* condition, but personally I would be using either `lock` (if you need to wait for it to complete), or maybe `Interlocked` if you just need to know if it is active.

For example:

```
class A
{
    private readonly object syncLock = new object();
    public object SyncLock { get { return syncLock; } }
    public void Update()
    {
        lock(SyncLock)
        {

            //(...do stuff...)

        }
    }
}
```

and

```
void Update()
{
    lock(a_inst.SyncLock)
    {
        (...do stuff...)
    }
}
```

With the above, you are guaranteed that only one thread will have the lock at any time, so if you get to "do stuff" you *know* that it isn't also running the other Update(). If you need to *wait* etc there are also `Wait()` / `Pulse()` methods against locks, or you can use gates such as `ManualResetEvent`/`AutoResetEvent`.

Things like `lock` also ensure correct memory barriers between the threads, so you see the correct data.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I understand now but just to clarify: What the lock command does is it ties down the object and prevents its execution by any other threads, in the event another thread has the object locked it waits for it to be free before allowing the body of code inside it to execute?

Comment: @meds - as long as by "the object" you mean the one in `SyncLock`, yes. Note that the other threads must *also* use `lock` for this to work - nothing is automatically locked. But yes, to get inside the `lock` statement you know you have an *exclusive* take on that lock

Comment: So if 5 threads locked the same SyncLock object it means they would each have to wait until the other threads were done before being allowed to execute passed the lock function? If so are the locks given linearly, i.e. first come first serve and standing in line sort of thing or is it random?

Comment: @meds yes, all 5 callers must use `lock` for this to work - any not using `lock` will simply walk in unimpeeded; re the order; you'd have to check the docs on that; I suspect linearly, but I can't see it stated. It refers to a ready ***queue***, but that's about it

Answer (score 2):

This situation can happen when the `Update` function has not been called yet. Just because you have called `Start` on the thread doesn't mean it's immediately going to execute it's main function. I'm not 100% sure if there is a slight window of opportunity where the thread is still alive but the main function has finished executing.

Basically you want to have a look at `ManualResetEvent` or `AutoResetEvent` to signal that your thread has finished working. Alternatively an event you can raise after `Update()` has finished and `B` can subscribe to might be good enough. Like this:

```
class A
{
    public event EventHandler UpdateFinished;

    public void Update()
    {
          ... do work

        var handler = UpdateFinished;
        if (handler != null)
        {
             handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}

class B
{
    public void Draw()
    {
        a_inst.UpdateFinished += HandleUpdateFinished;
        ... start your thread
    }

    private void HandleUpdateFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         ... do whatever
    }
}
```